# Monitoring c3p0 connections using Jconsole

Tags: c3p0, jconsole

Hi I am trying to monitor the connections opened by c3p0 using JConsole.

I am following tutorial mentioned in 
http://amemon.wordpress.com/2007/07/15/monitoring-c3p0-using-jmxjconsole/

But when I open the jconsole under Mbeans tab I am not able to find package for C3P0.

Any ideas??

Comment: when you start jconsole, have your c3p0 DataSources already been initialized? (ie have you seen c3p0's config dump, logged at INFO?)

Comment: yes. it was initialized at startup of my tomcat server

Comment: and in your logs (search if you can to be sure), at INFO, you do not see the following, from a logger named com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.C3P0Registry, "jdk1.5 management interfaces unavailable... JMX support disabled." and you can connect to the JVM with jconsole and see other MBeans?

Comment: No this log is not present.

Comment: Any suggestions on this? I m still stuck!!!

Comment: So, it sounds like you do, but you never answered: 1) do you successfully connect to the VM? [ If not, see https://gist.github.com/swaldman/5529452 ] 2) Do you see other active mbeans, e.g. the ones under java.lang?

Comment: I've now the same issue.,.. i see all the default java beans but not mchange..